# Checking PHP 5.4 code with Sonar - unable to parse informations in phpdepend output file

Tags: php, sonarqube

I am using [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) for QA with PHP. Currently I have started to using **traits** in source codes but since that, Sonar fails to analyse the source code with phpdepend - it is not able to parse informations in phpdepend output file. I have found that this is a [Bug in Sonar's PHP plugin](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-2303). This bug effectively disables using Sonar's PHP Plugin for PHP 5.4 - which is really bad, as php5.3 is reaching end of life soon!

I do not want to believe that nobody uses sonar and QA for PHP 5.4, so there must some solution exists...

Comment: You might get a better answer asking here http://www.sonarsource.org/support/support/

Comment: @crypticツ For information, we (the Sonar team) are also watching the "sonar" tag on stackoverflow. But's it's true that most questions get asked on the Sonar User mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, despite the fact that this seems to be a little longer and that I need support for `pdepend` in sonar, I have hacked a "solution"

Rename your `pdepend` command to `pdepend_orig` and create new `pdepend` command:

```
echo "Renaming files that use traits to *.phphide"

grep --files-with-matches -re "use .*Trait" .  | rename -v s/.php/.phphide/
find -name "*Trait.php" | rename -v s/.php/.phphide/

echo "Running original pdepend"
pdependorig $@

echo "Renaming files that were hidden back to *.php"
find -name "*.phphide" | rename -v s/.phphide/.php/
```

It hides files where you are using Traits so that Traits are excluded from `pdepend`. As a hack, it works.

Answer (score 3):

There's an open JIRA ticket on this: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-2303

It's already scheduled for next version of the plugin, but feel free to vote for it.

Comment: Thank you, I have voted for this already (and posted the link to this bug in question) before, but I am surprised that nobody in PHP community except these 2 votes (sic!) is using it? So I thought that myaby somebody has some workaround, like removing problematic lines from phpdepend.

Comment: I have the same problem with php54 project with pdepend and sonar